# Finding the index of a key and value within an array using a wildcard in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have been working on an issue and I was able to get done what I need to get done in a relatively decent and acceptable way but I am curious as to why I ran into some of the problems I did.

I'm not too savvy with PowerShell or C# but I have some experience with Java, C++, and a few others. So, if I overlook something really simple, you'll have to forgive me. I'm not looking for a critique of my solution, just some insight into some of the blockades I came across.

What I needed to do was use Powershell to query an LDAP setting. I needed to know MaxConnIdleTime and I needed that either assigned to a variable or accessible through a subroutine [sic] (ex $ldapPolicies.MaxConnIdleTime) so that I could run it through a conditional statement.

Here is how I accomplished it:

`$ldap = Get-ADObject -SearchBase "CN=Query-Policies,CN=Directory` `Service,CN=Windows` `NT,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=$ENV:COMPUTERNAME,DC=$dc" -Filter` `'ObjectClass -like "queryPolicy"' -Properties ldapadminlimits`

```
$ldap = @($ldap.ldapadminlimits)

$ldap | %{
    if($_.startswith("MaxConnIdleTime")) {
        $match = $_
        }
    }
```

I tried NTDSUtil.exe, however, I couldn't redirect the "Show Values" to a text file to read from later and I couldn't write it to a variable in PowerShell.

I tried Start-Transcript and then ran NTDSUtil but it only recorded what occurred within PowerShell and not what happened in NTDSUtil.

Also, I tried giving all of the commands to NTDSUtil at once (NTDSUtil "ldap policies" "connections" "connect to server $ENV:COMPUTERNAME" q "Show Values") but PowerShell doesn't show anything in the console and I have press the exit sequence to return back to PS>.

I know that I could use LDP but I'm not too familiar with ADSI. Research appeared to say that going about attempting to get an LDPdump is a bit antiquated and I pretty much abandoned that attempt.

One of the issues that I had that caused me a small bit of frustration (and the reason I am asking this question) is why can I not search an array and find the index of an item using a wildcard? I tried doing this:

```
$ldap.IndexOf("MaxConnIdleTime*")
```

AND

```
$ldap.IndexOf($ldap -like "MaxConnIdleTime*")
```

but it always returned -1.

It would work correctly if I tried:

```
$ldap.IndexOf("MaxConnIdleTime=100")
```

given that the value was indeed 100. But I am validating that the value was correct.

I know that I could just do something like this:

```
if($ldap -contains "MaxConnIdleTime=100") {
    DO SOMETHING...
    } else {
        DO SOMETHING ELSE...
        }
```

Why is it that I can't search an array using a wildcard operator? There was no ambiguity, so, it should have worked, right?

**I'm not looking for a critique of how I accomplished this,** I'm just wanting to understand why it behaved like it did.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a straightforward "search an array by wildcard and return an index" cmdlet, method, statement, etc. in PowerShell.

`.IndexOf` is not designed to work with a wildcard.

When you used the `-like` operator on the array, you likely found only a single matching object, but `-like` returns an array of matches when used on an array.

Passing the array into `.IndexOf()` then looks for an array element that is itself an array, even if that array only has one object.

This would work:

```
$ldap.IndexOf(($ldap -like "MaxConnIdleTime*")[0])
```

As long as you always wanted to find the first one.

Comment: I did not know that the comparison operator -like returns an array. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: @Rincewind it does but only when the left side is an array, same goes for `-match`. Otherwise it returns a `[bool]`. See [about_Comparison_Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx).